# What is the easiest way to back-up and archive DVD's to another DVD?

Tags: backup, dvd, archive

Preferably a all in one software package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brasero can do the trick. Just copy from one DVD to another of the same size. Or were you thinking something more complex?
If you are I'll add more applications (leave a comment).

Comment: Just make sure that your destination DVDs are the right size! Most DVDs around are 4.7GB. A movie-carrying DVD is going to be about 7-8 GB. You won't be able to do a disk-to-disk copy if you have anything smaller.

Comment: "Just copy from one DVD to another of the same size." lol.

Answer (score 0):

[K9Copy](http://k9copy.sourceforge.net/) will compress the DVD onto a 4.7GB medium. Unfortunately, it brings a number of KDE libraries with it. But it is very reliable, especially when paired with [K3b](http://www.k3b.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Brasero or k3b for this. Look for the function "clone CD/DVD".